# error C2512: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>' : no appropriate default constructor available with Visual Studio only

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, ostream

I'm asking this question because I'm a bit helpless: this error occurs ONLY with Visual Studio, GCC compiles it without errors or even warnings. Since this is some portable code I'm looking for a solution that works with both compilers (and in best case with no platform-dependent `ifdefs`).

> error C2512: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>' : no appropriate
>   default constructor available

happens while constructing an object of type MyObject that is defined as

```
   class MyObject : public Socket, public std::ostream
```

What special `ostream` parameters are expected by VS here?

Comment: Even i am also getting same issue in visual studio 2013 Error 1 error C2512: 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' : no appropriate default constructor available Error please can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::ostream` is a type alias for `std::basic_ostream<char>`. The constructor of `std::basic_ostream<char>` expects a pointer to a stream buffer to which the output stream is associated. You must provide one.

The signature of the constructor is the following one:

```
 explicit basic_ostream( std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>* sb );
```

Your class constructor should look something like this:

```
class MyObject : public Socket, public std::ostream
{
    MyObject(/* ... */) 
        : 
        std::ostream(/* provide a ptr to a stream buffer here /*) 
    //  ...
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Also see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream) for a reference.

Comment: Great answer.  I'm doing a migration to VS2012 from VS2008(and older) and this came up.